# How to edit style of popup in AutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I change style (background and border) of the popup in AutoCompleteBox in Windows Phone 8, xaml, c#?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the control template, as those properties in the default template are not styleable.  You might want to make a new style, or you could just override the existing one.  Here is the default style (in the Toolkit source under `Themes/Generic.xaml`):

```
<Style TargetType="controls:AutoCompleteBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Margin="8,7"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0,6,4"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:AutoCompleteBox">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox
                        x:Name="Text"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                        FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                        FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        InputScope="{TemplateBinding InputScope}"
                        Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <ListBox
                            x:Name="Selector"
                            Background="White"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                            FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}"
                            ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                            Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}"
                            Padding="0,8"/>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So you could just hard-code a new color for the ListBox in the Popup, eg:

```
                        <ListBox
                            x:Name="Selector"
                            Background="Black"
                            BorderBrush="Red"
```

---

Alternately, you could make the border/background styleable, but the same color as for the TextBox:

```
                        <ListBox
                            x:Name="Selector"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
```

This way, styles you apply to instances of the control will apply to both the TextBox and the Popup:

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" ... />
```

Comment: @user3852834 if should be in your project where, under the WP toolkit?  If not, you can download the source: http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP7/Themes/Generic.xaml